# GetRecordInfoFromGuids() fails with TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED

Tags: c++, com, typelib

[GetRecordInfoFromGuids()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails with error `TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED/-2147319779/0x8002801DL` on a virtual machine, but on my development machine, it works fine:

```
HRESULT hr = GetRecordInfoFromGuids(rGuidTypeLib, 1, 0, 0, __uuidof(T), &pRecInfo);
```

At the same time, I can successfully create instances of the COM server using `CoCreateInstance()`, only this function fails, so it must have registered.

**Edit:** I suspect it might be because I have specified an incorrect `uVerMajor` and `uVerMinor`. How can I check what is the version actually registered on the target machine?

Comment: You can check with `1` COM/OLE Viewer, which lists type libraries, and `2` by looking at registry under `HCKR\TypeLib` (also version numbers can be found threre as well).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it was because I was registering my COM server but not the typelib.

I was using this:

```
RegAsm.exe /codebase MyComServer.dll
```

Changing it to this fixed the problem:

```
RegAsm.exe /register /tlb:MyComServer.tlb /codebase MyComServer.dll
```